# Copy and paste fix number of rows from all the sheets and paste into one sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to Copy data of ("A1:A10") & ("D1:D10") columns from 10 sheets and paste it into a new sheet called("New1").
while it is copying the data it should not consider the new sheet("New1") as it is the results file.
and all the results should be appending under each other

Below is the code that i've tried . But I am getting an error "function not defined" on "Next ws"

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 

    Range("b3").Select 
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("New1").Select
    Range("A1").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 

Next ws 

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the code you tried? We will surely help you to correct it to make it work, but this website is not made for asking other people to do the work for you ;)

Comment: Sure , Below is the code that i've tried . But getting error on "Next ws"
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Range("b3").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("New1").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub                                                                                                                                          
  it's says function not defined,

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "New1" Then ' if current sheet isn't "New1" one
        With ws ' reference current sheet
            .Range("b3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("New1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy referenced sheet range from B3 down to last not empty cell and paste it form first empty cell of sheet "New1" column A
        End With
    End If
Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

and easily tweak it to handle different copying and pasting ranges

Comment: @JiteshVacheta, any feedback?